# Why Document Fields Still Have Uppercase Characters after Using LowerCaseFilterFactory?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I think an analyzer should apply both the indexing and search processes, correct? If true, why my document fields still have uppercase characters after using the **LowerCaseFilterFactory** filter in an analyzer?

I use Luke to check my document fields.

Here is my related code.

```
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "remarksAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class) , filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English") }) })
public class Book {
    ...
    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Analyzer(definition = "remarksAnalyzer")
    private String remarks;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to search on your index with lowercased words? I'm pretty sure it will work.

The fact is, if you use store=Store.YES, you will store the unanalyzed string in your index AND the analyzed tokens. This might allow you to use the highlighter for instance: to get an highlighted string, you need the original value.

Luke probably displays to you the stored value and not the tokens that are indexed.

Comment: Yes, it indeed works, searching using the lower-cased and upper-cased words both return the correct results. Thanks for your explanation, it solves my confusion.

Comment: I just exported the index to a file in Luke (_clicking the menu item Tools > Export index to XML_), and found the exported file contains both the analyzed value and the original value, such as follows: `<term field='field1' text='mny79bg2snm0kq4qhcrr' docFreq='1'/>` and `<field name='field1' flags='Idfp--S--N---------------'><val>mnY79bG2snM0Kq4QhCRR</val></field>`. It should verify your explanation. Thanks, Guillaume.